# Unable to log-in from Cloud Foundry CLI to Bluemix Dedicated

Tags: node.js, authentication, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

I am unable to log-in to my Bluemix Dedicated instance from the Cloud Foundry CLI.  I get a "FAILED" status, saying

> "Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:"

I am trying to use the API endpoint of `myapp.subdomain.bluemix.net`.  This is what is listed in my Bluemix app dashboard as the route to my app.

Comment: It turned out I was using the wrong subdomain.  Once I changed the API to use the correct subdomain, I was able to login and find my organization.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint for your Bluemix Dedicated environment is relative to the base URL. In your case it would be:

```
https://api.subdomain.bluemix.net
```

Some background on [Bluemix Public and the API endpoints is here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/whatisbluemix.html#ov_intro_reg).

Answer (score 0):

When you log into Bluemix using Cloud Foundry, set your API endpoint to:

`https://api.ng.bluemix.net` (or whatever region/subdomain you are currently using).

---

See the complete docs here:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/cfcommands/index.html